# REST webservice url to get only json data in google cloud

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am new to google cloud webservices. I have created one application in android to get JSON from a web services but it is fetching a complete HTML page as output. I need to know , how do we get path so that we can get only JSON data as output.

I am using HTTPGet() to add the url of our webservice.

Need your help for this.

Comment: Have you tried the accept header? Accept: application/json

Comment: I am getting JSON after executing the webservice , but I need to get the url only for json data.

Comment: where can I find **accept header**

Comment: I have added the header : Cache-Control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  181
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Tue, 12 May 2015 06:50:08 GMT
Etag:  "RVnsJG1fymcrzRYhQBKA9XACS8w/QBC06C5kdBYpivmfx2PUBPZfEMg"
Expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:  no-cache
Server:  GSE

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: I have added this as url : https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://1-dot-androidservice123456.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/sanjaywebservies1234567/v1/sanjaywebservies1234567.tabledata?_h=3& ........is this correct?